# Get Devise's model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have:

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :admins
```

Then, on Sign In page, i want to show 'Admin Sign In' title when someone tries to access /admins/sign_in

How it could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scoped views, they're described in the [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#readme), in the "Configuring views section".

Run:

```
rails generate devise:views admins
```

and set the following in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

You can then modify `app/views/admins/sessions/new.html.erb`, which will only get used when logging in as an admin.

If the view does not exist, it will fall back on `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to change the title of the page in the admin sign in view you could change the title in your routes file as follows:

`devise_for :admins, :path_names => { :sign_in => "Admin Sign In" }`